# How can I make a grid using " | " and " _ " on java?

Tags: java, loops, methods, conditional-statements

I'm a beginner at Java, and my programming teacher gave us an assignment that we need to make a grid of little squares using "|" and "_".
[Assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wC7zX.png)

I know this might look stupid, but it was the best that I could do. I managed to make the columns, but now I don't know how to make the rows.

```java
package practice;

public class practice {
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
    
    squares(4);
        
    }
    
    
    public static void squares(int number) {
        for (int i=0; i<number; i++) {
        System.out.print(" _");
        }
            System.out.println();
    
        for (int i=0; i<number; i++) {
        System.out.print("|_");
        }
            System.out.print("|");
            System.out.println();
    
    }
    
}
```

Until now I have learned how to use conditionals and loops, and this assignment is about using methods.

Comment: Post your code as text in the question, do not post images of it

Comment: For that first top-line, temporarily replace the `_` with `=`, just to see what happens ...

Comment: Your beginning of solution is interesting because you mentally decomposed in rows and noticed this particularity: there is 1 more "boundary" than the number or squares in a grid. You seemed to have traduced this idea with having a separate loop for the top line. First advice: your function "square" should be called "row" to fit to what it currently does. Another advice: the concept of rectangles in programming usually involves 2 nested loops, cubes would involve 3 nested loops, etc

Comment: Carefully inspect your output. Your inner side-walls are doubled - think about why that is so?

Comment: You should edit the question to show example input and actual output. If reasonable, the assignment should also be in text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: "is about using methods" - I can think of two methods: 1) receiving number of columns to print one row; 2) receiving both number of rows and columns to print all rows, using the first method - eventually these methods would also receive the character/string used as borders (a third method could be to print each cell) || BTW the problem can be solved without implementing methods in one line using the `repeat()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want it to. Use `java.util.Scanner` to get the input of the user for the number of rows and the number of columns. Then print the squares with some `for`-loops. If you are concerned about efficiency use `StringBuilder` instead, but I didn't use it here to keep it simple.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printGrid();
    }

    public static void printGrid() {
        // get input
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter rows");
        int rows = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter columns");
        int cols = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.close()

        // print top line
        if (rows > 0) {
            System.out.print(" ");  // padding
            for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
                System.out.print("_ ");
            }
            System.out.println();  // new line
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            // print left line
            System.out.print("|");
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                System.out.print("_|");
            }
            System.out.println();  // new line
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was very helpful, I was analysing the logic you used and it was very clear after I understood.  Thank you so much for it.

Answer (score 3):

I put some spoiler so first you can try to solve it on your own.

If you carefully observe this, how many rows do you see?

```
 _ _ 
|_|_|
|_|_|
```

> 3 rows, always one more due to the 'header' one: `_ _`

How many of those follow the same pattern?

> all but not the first one

You can achieve that with this code:

> `public static void main(String[] args) {`
>     `generateSquare(2, 2);`
> `}`
> `private static void generateSquare(int qtyRows, int qtyCols) {`
>     `System.out.println(" ".repeat(qtyCols));`
>     
>     `for(int x = 0; x < qtyRows; x++) {`  
>       `System.out.println("|" + "|".repeat(qtyCols));`
>     `}`
> `}`

Note the use of the repeat method on a String object, that let you repeat that string without the need of a loop.

Comment: That is amazing. I did not know about this repeat code, very simple to understand too. But I did not get that ">!" at the end of the code, what is that for?

Comment: @DanielMases glad to help you :) (that ">!" was a copy-paste error, I removed it thanks)

Comment: @DanielMases and welcome to the amazing world of Java programming ;-)

Comment: @DanielMases see my edit, I added a method

Comment: Thank you so much for it. It has been difficult so far, but I'm committed to get better at this. Really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using the *[StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)*, and *[Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html)*, classes.

```java
void draw(int r, int c) {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    Formatter f = new Formatter(s);
    f.format("%s%n", " _".repeat(c));
    for (int i = 0, j; i < r; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++) f.format("|_");
        f.format("|%n");
    }
    f.flush();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output

```
 _ _
|_|_|
|_|_|
```

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
```